# Regular expression to grep command for linux

Tags: linux

I have this line in my text file:

```
[Tue Mar 01 21:28:58.377941 2016] [evasive20:error] [pid 5098] [client 192.168.163.1:3978] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/test.php
```

I grep this sentence with the command

```sh
grep "evasive20"
```

In the result, the whole sentence is shown. But I want to output the lines containing "evasive20" and delete the `[pid 5098]` part in them, so that the result showing will be:

```
[Tue Mar 01 21:28:58.377941 2016] [evasive20:error] [client 192.168.163.1:3978] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/test.php
```

Is that possible in a single command? Or is there any way for me to grep the front part and the last part for the sentence (without the `[pid xxxx]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `sed` can both find the line(s) you need and modify it:

```
$ sed '/evasive20/ s/\[pid [0-9]*\] //' <your-file.log
```